# tilde notation for random variables

Tags: probability-theory, notation, random-variables

what does $X,Y \sim U(\{1,\dots ,n\})$ mean, where $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables.
Does it just mean that $X$ and $Y$ are defined on $[1,n]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that means that these two random variables have a uniform distribution over integers $1, \dots, n$.

Answer (score 1):

Although @DF has already published his/her answer, I'm still writing one in response to your question.

> Does it just mean that $X$ and $Y$ are defined on $[1,n]$?

No, note the difference between $\{1,\dots,n\}$ and $[1,n]$.

| set | $\{1,\dots,n\}$ | $[1,n]$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| in words | set of integers from $1$ to $n$ | closed interval from $1$ to $n$ |
| finite set? | yes | no |